# Constraint Layout Issue

Tags: android, android-studio

This is the code that I keep getting an error when I try to put it into Constraint Layout. I have tried numerous different methods to allow the constraint layout to appear successfully on the profile page. However, I still have been unsuccessful with getting the name to display without being jumbled together.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/graylight"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="260dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradientbackground"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="425dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/jussim" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="Justina Simone"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="21sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/IVaddfriend"
        android:layout_width="425dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_person_add_black_24dp" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/IVimage1"
        android:layout_width="425dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_message_black_24dp"
        tools:ignore="InvalidId" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/IVimage2"
        android:layout_width="425dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_grade_black_24dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show us some code please

Comment: @HocineB Please see the revised post.

Comment: Show the output you're getting now.

Comment: @HEWhoDoesn'tKnow It's not giving me output. My code just becomes red after adding the constraint layout code.

Comment: @CassandraCampbell you're saying that you have an error in constraint layout, but in here your're using linear.

Comment: Please check for this line in your build.gradle file and if it's missing then add it in the file                                                                             
                                                                                                                   
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

Comment: @Shehroz That line was missing from my build.gradle file. However, when I add it I get an error that says expecting EOF, found ":".

Comment: @HEWhoDoesn'tKnow Is it not possible to place the linear layout into a constraint layout?

Comment: @CassandraCampbell In order to use constraint layout you have to add its dependency in gradle file. Check this link it will help you with your problem https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/